# How to use ASP.NET Resource(.resx) strings from within javascript files

Tags: javascript, asp.net, localization, resources

How would one get resx resource strings into javascript code stored in a .js file?

I want to perform some validation in separate .js file and I want to get the messages from resx file to achieve Localization

Answer (score 0):

You could write a handler (*.axd) that returns javascript  with the messages

How to write a handler: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001